# Reffering to View from method while using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I access the `Views` of my `layout` from my own method while using `Fragments`? I have my `View` set up in `Fragment` like this:

```
public class LeftSectionFragment extends Fragment {
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left, container, false);

            TextView whatever = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.whateverR);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

How to access this `whatever TextView` field so I could write down something in there using my own method? Just like `whatever.setText()` but I can not use it as I do not know how to refer to it from outside of the `Fragment`.

EDIT: My method **(it is not inside `LeftSectionFragment`!)** from where I want to refer to `TextView` looks like this:

```
    private void print(String msg) {
    String s = msg;
    inc = s.split(",");
    incLength = inc.length;

    //here refer to whatever TextView, similiary to whatever.setText(inc[0])
}
```

EDIT2: Main `onCreate` method where fragments are first brought up:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());        


    mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });


    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

}
```

FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return new LeftSectionFragment();

            case 1:
                return new MiddleSectionFragment();

            case 2:
                return new RightSectionFragment();

            default:
                return new MiddleSectionFragment();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            int pos = position;
            switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                return "Left";
            case 1:
                return "Middle";
            case 2:
                return "Right";
            default:
                return "Middle";
            }
        }
    }
```

Tabs:

```
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }
```

EDIT3: Where `print` is brought up:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
            readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
            print(readMessage);
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly your question but I think you want something like that :

```
public class LeftSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView mWhatever;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left, container, false);

        mWhatever = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.whateverR);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void setWhateverText(String text) {
        mWhateverText.setText(text);
    }
}
```

And in your activity, access it like that :

```
{
    // init your Fragment
    LeftSectionFragment leftFragment = LeftSectionFragment.initiate(); 
}


private void print(String msg) {
    String s = msg;
    inc = s.split(",");
    incLength = inc.length;

    //here refer to whatever TextView, similiary to whatever.setText(inc[0])
    leftFragment.setWhateverText(incLength);
}
```

Comment: Please take a look for my post again if it changes anything. I edited it.

Comment: My second part of code isn't in the LeftSectionFragment neither, but in the Activity where you add your Fragment. I edited my answer, maybe it'll help.

Comment: What is the best place to put the `LeftSectionFragment leftFragment = LeftSectionFragment.initiate(); ` in?

Comment: Well, how are you initializing your fragment LeftSectionFragment ? Via xml layout ?

Comment: Added the whole code which brings the fragments up. Please take an insight, I really am hopeless about that...

Comment: When is your "print()" method called ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
private void print(String msg) {
    String s = msg;
    inc = s.split(",");
    incLength = inc.length;
    LeftSectionFragment.set(inc[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < incLength; i++)
        Log.i("taguś",inc[i]);
}
```

Here, we are just making a reference to the `LeftSectionFragment` where we have a method:

```
public static void set(String text) {
    valuefixInd.setText(text);
}
```

And it is all good. Important to do is to define our `Fragment` class, `TextView` field and `set` method to be static: `private static TextView whatever` & `public static class LeftSectionFragment extends Fragment` & `public static void set`.